# awk: substituting strings for decimals and summing

Tags: awk

I have strings that are supposed to match with decimal numbers.

For example,

```
one is equal to 1
too 2
hello 4
pots 16
```

and they are separated by '-' and these are the only ones used, so

```
one-one sums to 2
One-oNe sums to 2
one-one-too-one sums to 5
```

It is not case sensitive!

Now, I have a file that separates columns with ; and I want to **write an awk expression that checks if the SUM of the first column $1 is equal to $2**.

Here is an example of how the file is structured

```
oNe-oNE ; 2
one-too ; 1
```

and this is the desired output

```
oNe-oNE ; 2 ; match
one-two ; 1 ; not
```

I know how to sum digits in a column in awk (ex: awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}') , but I don't know how to make strings correspond to numbers and then sum them. Should I use regex and substitute?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `awk` solution:

```
cat key
one 1
too 2
hello 4
pots 16
```

```
cat file
oNe-oNE ; 2
one-too ; 1
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {split($1,b,"-");f=tolower(b[1]);s=tolower(b[2]);print $0,"; "(a[f]+a[s]==$3?"match":"not")}' key file
oNe-oNE ; 2 ; match
one-too ; 1 ; not
```

---

Added `key` file inn to the `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=split("one 1 too 2 hello 4 pots 16",b," ");for (i=1;i<n;i+=2) a[b[i]]=b[i+1]} {split($1,c,"-");f=tolower(c[1]);s=tolower(c[2]);print $0,"; "(a[f]+a[s]==$3?"match":"not")}' file
oNe-oNE ; 2 ; match
one-too ; 1 ; not
```

Comment: thank you, let me know if you can think of a way to do this without a 'key' file.

Comment: @user3295674 Do you like the key data stored in the  `awk`, or in an variable.

Comment: Either way is fine, I think in a variable inside the script would be fantastic!

Comment: @user3295674 Post updated.  If its ok, please accept it.

Comment: it's almost correct but it doesn't work if the input includes something like, which should give a match, POTS-heLLO-Hello-HELLO : 28 : match . Seems that when it's more than two chained words that it doesn't read them all.  *Should I edit the for loop to fix that?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that, I am sorry it came across as only two. I guess it should split and check for lower in a loop, so it handles all the arguments, even strings with one-one-too-TOO-many-LOTS-loTS (many more)

Comment: @user3295674 It solvable, but it would be complicated and long, and I dont have all that time, sorry.